# What exactly is neutron radiation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrons

Well, I'll be honest my physics is not good. But I really wonder about radiation and other physical stuff.

When I search about it I see three types of ionizing radiation: Alpha, Beta and Gamma. But when I search about nuclear weapons I see that they work by launching a neutron to a u235. So I wonder how is this neutron launched? I know that fission occurs 2 or 3 neutrons. But you need a neutron to start fission, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Neutron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_radiation) is what it sounds like - it is a type [ionising radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation) that consists of neutrons.

You are correct - to start a [nuclear chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_chain_reaction) in a fissile material such as $^{235}U$ there needs to be a source of neutrons. A large enough quantity (a [critical mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_mass)) of fissile material can spontaneously start its own chain reaction triggered by neutrons produced by its own decay or from background radiation. A [fission weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon#Fission_weapons) needs to trigger the chain reaction at a precisely controlled time. This is done by either smashing two sub-critical quantities of material together to create a critical mass, or by using conventional explosives to compress a sub-critical mass until it becomes critical.